# sp_send_dbmail resulting Excel attachment to include merged cells

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sp-send-dbmail

My need is to output the query result of a stored procedure as an Excel attachment to a selected audience using `sp_send_dbmail`. while I am able to achieve this I prefer to have few headers merged similar to the screenshot below. Is this possible using `sp_send_dbmail`? If not what is the work around for this? My dataset is too long to be included as an email body.

[Please click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs96e.jpg)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Have you read through the [sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql) documentation? Since you know that cannot generate Excel documents from `sp_send_dbmail` you must already be using some other process to generate them, so why didn't the `@file_attachments` parameter work for you to attach them?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that level of Excel formatting via sp_send_dbmail.  In my personal experience if I've had to do something like that then I have an SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) report that gets a scheduled subscription set up.  The SSRS report can have merged headers/cells, etc., and can be scheduled to be emailed in Excel format

Comment: Beyond that, I have not tried to do anything within SSIS, perhaps with scripting, to first export the data records to an Excel file and then maybe manipulate that file to add the header rows and merge the required cells - but it would be likely you could do something like that with scripting.

Comment: Thank you Craig, I will try that route of using SSRS.

Comment: Just a follow up question on this, I'm trying to send a Data dump from SSIS using sp_send_dbmail no customization formatting. This works perfectly for file size upto 19MB. And thereafter for bigger files, although the  mail doesn't fail in mail server , I do not receive any email. Is this due to outlook limitations? If so even if I use SSRS , would it not allow to send 80MB attachment?